# Animate child inside parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, gsap

I'm trying to animate a child div inside a parent div with TweenMax. The animation should start from a random position within the parent div (which is working pretty good). But the animation should not be able to go outside of the parent div. How can I make the child div animate from random start positions but not go outside of parent div?

This is my js so far:

```
var main = $('.outer');
var box = $('.inner');

var width = main.width();
var height = main.height();

$( '.inner' ).each(function( index ) {
  $(this).css({
    left : Math.random() * ($('.inner').width() - $(this).width()),
    top : Math.random() * ($('.inner').height() - $(this).height())
  });
});

function randomNumber(min, max) {
  return (Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

TweenLite.defaultEase = Linear.easeNone;
var tl = new TimelineLite()

tl.to(".inner", 3.05, {x:randomNumber(0, width), repeat:-1, yoyo:true})
  .to(".inner", 3.4, {y:randomNumber(0, height), repeat:-1, yoyo:true}, 0)
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdornell/7q8jnzq0/9/)

Comment: You can also click the `<>` to create a snippet here

Comment: Use `left: randomNumber(0, width - box.width())` and `top` instead of `y`, subtracting the height. You had it correct in the setup function... https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/7q8jnzq0/10/

Comment: Console.log `$('.inner').width() - $(this).width()`... I'm pretty sure it results in zero.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you very much! Not that used to TweenLite animations yet. I was a bit confused about the x position vs the left position.

Comment: @jdo Louys is right, you actually have it wrong in the setup. You need `Math.random * (main.width() - box.width())` and same for `height()`. (but it *was* correct in your fiddle...!?)